# What SQL query operations can change their value dependent on order?

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[see addendum below]

Recently I was going through an SQL script as part of a task to check functionality of a data science process. I had a copy of a section of the script which had multiple sub queries and I refactored it to put the sub queries up the top in a with-clause. I usually think of this as an essentially syntactic refactoring operation that is semantically neutral. However, the operation of the script changed.

Investigation showed that it was due to the use of a row number over a partition
in which the ordering within the partition was not complete. Changing the structure
of the code changed something in the execution plan, that changed the order within
the slack left by the incomplete ordering.

I made a note of this point and became less confident of this refactoring, although
I hold the position that order should not affect the semantics, at least as long as
it can be avoided.

My question is ...

other than assigning a row number, what operations have a value that is changed
by the ordering?

---

I realize now that the question was a bit too open - both answers below were useful to me, but I cannot pick one over the other as THE right answer. I have up-voted both. Thanks. [I rethought that, and will pick one of the answers, rather than none. The one I pick was a bit more on target].

I also realize that the core of the problem was my not having strongly enough in mind that any refactoring can potentially change the contingent order in which the rows are returned. From now on, if I refactor and it changes the result - I will look for issues with ordering.

Comment: This will be a hard question to answer by Stack Overflow. The first thing that comes to mind is anything with a LIMIT, but it's not clear what would the correct answer for this question be.

Comment: We tend to recommend using CTEs over sub-queries because that modularizes the code for readability, CTEs are better in general and makes it easier for optimizers to understand what you are attempting in your code. What would be helpful is to see the before and after code. Can you supply that?

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake All I did was to take a subquery out and put it up the top in the with-clause. Generically, "select * from fred, (select * from joe) " becomes "with sue as (select * from joe) select * from fred, sue". I don't think I made any mistakes in the actual refactoring move. It was just that it changed the output that put me off. I now feel that it was "just" that since the code effectively picked the 1st few items off the subquery, the change in structure caused an incidental and implementation dependent change in the order of the result from the subquery.

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake I do not think that SnowFlake was culpable here.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa You are very right there. I have made a note of that point in the post. But, I was also rather happy with the answers I got, despite this problem.

Comment: I appreciate you want to keep this high-level, but a reproducible test case would help. Obviously anything that gets a first/last or otherwise ordered result will depend on ordering, and that could have unpredictable effects if you use those results as a subquery etc to drive further clauses. I don't think anyone can list all possible unpredictable side effects, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I think you misread the intention of the question. The question was - which operations in SQL have a result that depends on the order of the table, not a request to list unpredictable side effects. I know the question was a bit awkward, but I did actually get a couple of good responses and asking this question in StackExchange really cleared up my mind on what was going on. I am currently grateful to the responders for the well considered responses.

Comment: @Bruce I don't see the difference. The side effects of relying on an unstable ordering are inherently unpredictable. The accepted answer more or less restates the issue you already described in the question, adding only a method for checking uniqueness of the sort keys. Did you learn about any other operations whose value is changed by the ordering?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson My take away was much more in what sort of reaction people had to the question. When I posted, I was feeling confused. But, interacting with the people here removed that confusion - regardless of whether they strictly answsered the question. I acknowledge that maybe I should not have marked any answer as correct - I was feeling that no exact answer was coming, and that I should pick someone. Maybe I should have left it marked as unanswered. But, I took the lack of answer as meaning that there were no other options - except for the one that I provided myself - arithmetic.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson one problem with giving examples here is that the point is that the order of the query result is detectable but is indeterminate. SQL has indeterminate behaviour. But, I will add some kind of example that works in SnowFlake, if you feel it would improve things. I am actually in agreement with you other than about the idea that there is no difference, but I think that this would be a long discussion - so I was avoiding it. I'd be up to a chat on this - if you wanted.

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake just wondering - do you know how to configure the default autocomplete behaviour on the SnowFlake interface. In particular, I want it to stop giving me the close quote whenever I write a quote.

Comment: that is annoying sometimes, have you tried using the new Snowsight? The logo recently changed from 'Preview App' to 'Snowsight' as they're nearing GA. Also, I am getting used to using PyCharm which has auto-complete too

Comment: @patrick_at_snowflake I was not aware of Snowsight. I will make a note and see if that helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When windowed functions are involved, especially the `ROW_NUMBER()` the first thing to check is if the columns used for ordering produce a stable sort.

For instance:

```
CREATE TABLE t(id INT, grp VARCHAR(100), d DATE, val VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO t(id, grp, d, val)
VALUES (1, 'grpA', '2021-10-16', 'b')
      ,(2, 'grpA', '2021-10-16', 'a')
      ,(3, 'grpA', '2021-10-15', 'c')
      ,(4, 'grpA', '2021-10-14', 'd')
      ,(5, 'grpB', '2021-10-13', 'a')
      ,(6, 'grpB', '2021-10-13', 'g')
      ,(7, 'grpB', '2021-10-12', 'h');

-- the sort is not stable, d column has a tie
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY d DESC) AS rn
   FROM t) sub
WHERE sub.rn = 1 AND sub.val = 'a';
```

[image]

Depending of the order of operation it could return:

- 0 rows
- 1 row (id: 2)
- 1 row (id: 5)
- 2 rows(id: 2 and 5)

When query is refactored it could cause choosing a differnt path to access the data thus different result.

---

To check if sort is stable windowed COUNT could be used using all available columns:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT t.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY grp, d ) AS cnt
   FROM t) sub
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e730796b515e5dbc4abba403e317a5f6)**

Answer (score 3):

So are you saying to had gaps in the `row_numbers()`? or duplicate row_numbers? or just row numbers jumped around (unstable?)

Which functions are altered by incomplete/unstable order by functions, all the ones where you put OBER BY in the window function. Thus ROW_NUMBER or LAG or LEAD

But in general a sub-select and a CTE (with clause) are the same, the primary difference is multiple things can JOIN the same CTE (thus the Common part) this can be good/bad as you might save on some expensive calculation, but you might also slow down a critical path, and make the whole execution time slower.

Or the data might be a little more processed (due to JOIN's etc) and then the incomplete ODERBY/instability might be exposed.

Comment: The numbers jumped around resulting in different conclusions depending on the refactoring. Thinking about this - it was not really the refactoring in and of itself. For example, changing the version of the database engine might have had the same effect. Since I wrote the question, I have become a lot more clear in my own mind about what was going on. But/and I am really happy with the answers I got to this in Stack Exchange. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

SQL is not based on set theory but on list theory. It is true that many join-based operations have an output such that the underlying bag of elements is a function of the underlying bag of elements in the input - but there are operations, such as row_number() as mentioned, in which this is not the case.

I would like to add a more obscure effect not mentioned in the other answers so far. Floating point arithmetic. Since the order of adding up floating point numbers does actually make a difference, it is possible that using a different ordering clause can produce different floating point values.

In the case mentioned in the posted question, this did actually happen - although only in the 10th decimal place. But that can be enough to change which value is bigger than another, and so make a discrete and significant change to the result of the outermost query.

Comment: numerical instability of floating point numbers is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

Another example would be `LISTAGG`. I inherited some code that used `LISTAGG`, but didn't give consistent answers when I tweaked it, because it didn't include the ordering clause: `WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY ...)`.

From the [Snowflake docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/listagg.html):

> If you do not specify the WITHIN GROUP (<orderby_clause>), the order
> of elements within each list is unpredictable. (An ORDER BY clause
> outside the WITHIN GROUP clause applies to the order of the output
> rows, not to the order of the list elements within a row.)